# SVG Icons are Invisible

Tags: css, svg, bigcommerce

I'm working on a BigCommerce theme and somewhere along the way, the SVG icons that are inside buttons disappeared. I can't for the life of me figure out what style is causing them not to show.

Here's a link to an example page: https://brazos-sticks-dev7.mybigcommerce.com/twisted-oak-walking-cane/

Comment: the svg element that is supposed to contain the elements you are using is empty. So you are using an inexisting #icon-keyboard-arrow-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hit this issue in the past when adding custom SVGs to the sprite that contain `defs` in them. Review the SVGs you've added. Move those SVGs that have defs into your image folder and utilise them individually. Re-run `svgstore` and your icons will return.